# Representing multiple values using 3D Analyst's Interpolate Line Tool?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst

I need to create line transects over a city. There transects are then plotted in XY line graphs. What I am now struggling to do is create these line transects with numerous values represented within the graphs. The values representing the city are a mixture of raster and polygons

Comment: Can you draw a graphic and add it as an image to illustrate what you are describing?

Answer (score 2):

This should help if I understand the question correctly.

1. Create several line shapefiles to represent your transect lines.
2. Use the tool [Interpolate Shape (3D Analyst)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q90000006m000000), to give your lines z values based on the  elevation data.
3. Once step 2 is done, select the transects that you want to show in your xy line graph.
4. Using 3D analyst, click the Profile Graph button to bring up the profile of your transects. You don't need to worry about selecting any specific elevation data in the Layer window as your lines already have z defined.
5. When the Profile Graph window opens, right mouse click on the window and select export.
6. In the Export Dialog window, click the Data tab and select the Excel radio button. Click the save button and save it as a .xls
7. Use Excel to display the different transects as it gives you better control on presentation. Below is and example showing the same transect line with developed and undeveloped surface elevations.

[image]